# Incorrect syntax error when trying to concat few values in declared variable which is output to SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, casting

**I am using SQL 2005**

@empId is input parameter to SP which is INT.

Based on some logic, I am doing below in the IF ELSE statement, it throws error in OUTPUT line. basically I want to Concat. I tried to concat, no luck.

Please Note, @name is also input that is varchar(20)

```
DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(50)

@OUTPUT= 'Valid' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @empId) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) , @name)
```

**Error**

```
Incorrect syntax near '@Output'.
```

Comment: "I am using SQL 2005"    Let it go.   It's time...

Comment: @TabAlleman: I wish but not my voice heard in company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SET` or `SELECT`:

```
DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(50);

SET @OUTPUT = 'Valid' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @empId) + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @name);
```

You might find it more convenient to do `replace()`:

```
SET OUTPUT = 'Valid @empId @name';
SET @OUTPUT = REPLACE(@OUTPUT, '@empId', @empId);
SET @OUTPUT = REPLACE(@OUTPUT, '@name', @name);
```

This is one way that I construct strings.  I think it is easier to handle the template and then just replace each of the elements, one at a time.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. it make me wait to accept answer. Will do..One quick question, hope we dont need convert statement for '@name'. Just @name would do as its already a varchar?

Comment: @Learner . . . You do not need to convert name.

Comment: Gordon, sorry forgot to vote yesterday, remembered to vote it now